# How to disable HTML checking in vim?

Tags: vim

I'm getting this HUGE message every single time I save an angular template (which is saved as a `.html` file):

```
|1 col 1| Warning: missing <!DOCTYPE> declaration
|1 col 1| Warning: inserting missing 'title' element
|| Info: Document content looks like HTML 4.01 Strict
|| Info: No system identifier in emitted doctype
|| 2 warnings, 0 errors were found!
|| 
|| 
|| To learn more about HTML Tidy see http://tidy.sourceforge.net
|| Please send bug reports to html-tidy@w3.org
|| HTML and CSS specifications are available from http://www.w3.org/
|| Lobby your company to join W3C, see http://www.w3.org/Consortium
```

How can I disable it?

Comment: How can I tell? :(

Comment: There's no such line at all. I double checked.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have something nonstandard in your vim installation or profile that invokes the external utility `htmltidy` when you save a file. This doesn't seem to be normal/standard.

See [Cleanup your HTML](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanup_your_HTML) for a variety of methods by which this sort of thing can be done.

I would use the command `:scriptnames` to list which configuration files are loaded by vim and then scrutinize each of them for htmltidy.

You may have a file named `html.vim` in a location searched by vim at startup.